# Destination address not shown in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, contiki

I am simulating a flooding attack using disturber motes in cooja. I also save the radio message in a log file(.pcap). But when i run the file using wireshark, it does not show me the destination address of the the packet send by disturber motes although it is sent. Can anyone give me hint or tips on solving this?

[Cooja](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbrHc.png)

[Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JT8m.png)

Comment: Is it possible to add ipv6 address for disturber mote?